# Special characters and RODBC

Tags: r, special-characters, rodbc

in a database I have strings stored that contain special characters such as "§".
Using the command

`sqlQuery()`

from package RODBC "§" is translated to "?". This is also the case for characters such as " ' " as it can be found in French words.

Of course I can not replace every "?" by one of the special characters after the query. Does anybody have an idea for this problem? I work under windows 7.

As requested the out put of `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] timeDate_2160.97 gridExtra_0.9.1  reshape2_1.2.2   RODBC_1.3-6      ggplot2_0.9.3.1  plyr_1.8        
[7] Runiversal_1.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-1   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.3       gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-21       
 [7] munsell_0.4        proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_2.14.1
```

Comment: I think you need to set the `DBMSencoding` in `odbcDriverConnect()` to whatever the database is encoded in. I guess `"UTF-8"` would be worth a start.

Comment: Any joy setting the encoding?

Comment: I try soon and tell you - thanks!

Comment: @SimonO101 I tried to set the DBMSencoding right in odbcConnect I tried: odbcConnect(mydb, uid=myuid,pwd=mypwd,DBMSencoding="UTF-8")   but this did not solve the problem. I don't know how to use odbcDriverConnec but additional arguments to odbcConnect should be passed on.

Comment: @SimonO101 I have checked it. The syntax odbcConnect("XX", uid="YY",pwd="ZZ",DBMSencoding="UTF-8"); passes the DBMSencoding to odbcDriverConnect. But still I get "?" instead of "§" ...

Comment: @SimonO101 I have checked again: the charset of the database is UTF8 and I can pass it to odbcConnect but still I don't get the "§" ...

Comment: is their any solution ? I have the same issue while connecting my access database with R.

Comment: I did not solve this issue so far.

Comment: did any got answer for this. I do got struck here

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing an issue where you are using sqlSave() in R to send to MYSQL where not all of the data streams through, it's likely because of special characters. The key is to make sure the character collation is set to the same in both..I found latin1 works best.